# List all the permutations for the letters $a,c,t$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know a permutation is $p(n,r)=\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ but I am confused how to go about solving this problem. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

The formula $$p(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$ gives the number of ways of ordering $r$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.  (I find it easier to think of $p(n,r)=\binom{n}{r} r!$; we choose $r$ elements and can order them in $r!$ ways.)

In this case, we're listing the ways of ordering all of the elements from a set of $3$ elements.  So we have $r=n=3$, and we have $p(3,3)=3!/(3-3)!=6$.

But we don't just want to count them, we want to list them too.  I.e., we want to write what the number $p(3,3)=6$ is counting.

In this case the $6$ permutations are:

```
act atc tac tca cat cta
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of combination. Permutation is the number of ways that you can arrange a group of things without repeating something that has already been used. You have three letters in your set, so we should have $3!=6$ permutations. Explicitly, they are {a,c,t},{a,t,c},{t,a,c},{t,c,a},{c,a,t},{c,t,a}

Comment: doesn't order matter in a permutation? Wouldn't that mean switching the order wouldn't count as another group?

Comment: Order does matter with permutation. Not with combination. In the formula you provided above, we are in the case of r=3

Answer (score 0):

When I was in school I decided to disregard use of $P(n,r)$. I think a better way of approaching these questions is by the multiplication principle (or the axiom of choice). Basically, pretend you have 3 boxes. In the first box you can put 3 letters. In the second box you can only put 2 letters (since 1 has gone to the first box). Finally the third box can have only 1 letter. Therefore the number of permutations you can make is $3 \times 2 \times 1 = 6$.